# Reading tables larger than RAM in R

Tags: r

I have a large table to pull from SQL. The data is over the 16GBs of RAM that I have allotted on my computer. I figure I could pull the data in a couple parts, but it requires that R completely releases the memory.

In psuedo code this would look like the following

```
pull first 1/3 of data
write data

restart R

pull 2/3 of data
write data

restart R

pull final 3/3 of data
write data
```

I know of the `.rs.restartR()` command in Rstudio, but I was curious if there was a more general solution that did no depend on IDE.

Also, if there are other ways to save large tables in R (larger than RAM) that does not require restart I would be interested in that solution also.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_use_R_language_for_larger_datasets_of_size_more_than_a_machine_RAM_size first google result

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. I have to `rm()` then `gc()` not one or the other.

Comment: see the [high performance task view](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=HighPerformanceComputing)